# How to generate fcs after using flowcut

Tags: r

I´m new in the R community and I´m not so efficient. I´m trying to clean `fcs` files using `flowCut`.
When I use `flowcut`, it's generating a large list and not a large flow frame. Then it´s not possible to export as `FCS` file using `write.FCS`. How do I export the results of flow clean as an `FCS`? Thanks for your help. Here is my console screenshot:

[image: Screenshot Rstudio]

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that `write.FCS()` expects the file name to be of type "character," i.e. a string wrapped in quotation marks. Does changing your last line to `write.FCS(res_flowcut$frame, "D:/WD/outfile")` resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi mvb, welcome to Stack Overflow. As you may see, I edited your answer to provide a bit more detail. Also, I'm not sure you've addressed the first part of the OP's question, which was about the output from `flowcut()`. Can you revise your answer to address both parts of the OP's issues and give a bit more detail about what you're suggesting and why?